# How to handle POSTed XML via Sinatra Ruby app

Tags: xml, ruby, web-services, sinatra

I'm planning on using Sinatra for a new tiny webservice (WS) that I need to put together for a client.

The WS will only have two methods, one accessed via GET and one via POST.  For the POST method, the client will send an XML packet to the sinatra WS which will parse the data and issue either a 200 OK HTTP response or a 40x error code.

My question is how do I parse the incoming POSTed XML packet in Sinatra?

Here is an example of what the incoming data packet will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Counts>
  <OccupiedCount>300</OccupiedCount>
  <ReservedCount>40</ReservedCount>
  <VacantCount>160</VacantCount>
  <TotalCount>500</TotalCount>
  <Checksum>0777d5c17d4066b82ab86dff8a46af6f</Checksum>
  <Timestamp>2009-11-21T14:06:19Z</Timestamp>
  <ApiKey>1234567890qwerty</ApiKey>
</Counts>
```

Is there someway to access the data packet via the Sinatra params object so that I can parse it with something like Crack XML?  Or do I need to use some kind of Rack variable to get at the whole XML data packet that was POSTed to my WS?

Comment: See http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro for a good guide to handling requests in Sinatra, & in particular http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  This question was asked back in 2009 in the earlier days of Sinatra

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that when I came here from a related question.

Answer (score 0):

sinatra app

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

post '/form' do
    puts params[:xml]
end
```

Posting a request using your data:

```
curl -d "xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Counts>
  <OccupiedCount>300</OccupiedCount>
  <ReservedCount>40</ReservedCount>
  <VacantCount>160</VacantCount>
  <TotalCount>500</TotalCount>
  <Checksum>0777d5c17d4066b82ab86dff8a46af6f</Checksum>
  <Timestamp>2009-11-21T14:06:19Z</Timestamp>
  <ApiKey>1234567890qwerty</ApiKey>
</Counts>
" http://localhost:4567/form
```

Result:

```
- - [11/Nov/2009:12:05:40 PST] "POST /form HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /form
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=utf-8 ?>
<Counts>
  <OccupiedCount>300</OccupiedCount>
  <ReservedCount>40</ReservedCount>
  <VacantCount>160</VacantCount>
  <TotalCount>500</TotalCount>
  <Checksum>0777d5c17d4066b82ab86dff8a46af6f</Checksum>
  <Timestamp>2009-11-21T14:06:19Z</Timestamp>
  <ApiKey>1234567890qwerty</ApiKey>
</Counts>
```

Comment: Don't know why the xml data gets garbled but it definitely works on my machine

Comment: the data isn't coming in as an XML= param though.  its just the whole data packet, not a packet that starts with "XML=<xml data here />" so params[:xml] doesn't exist in this case

Comment: it doesn't seem that request.body works as its not a string object, and request.POST is a hash, not the whole object

Comment: I found the answer.  I can access 
    request.body.read
to get the data packet

Comment: Please edit your answer to format your examples better. The formatting is wrong causing sections of your XML to be hidden. See the [formatting help section](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more info. I'd reformat it for you but I am not sure what you intend for some of the examples and results.